Find the segment BT in the right triangle below
In the right triangle $ABC$, $AE = 9m$ and $EB = 3m$.
Calculate $BT$.(Answer: 6m)

I try:
$BT^2 = BM.BC = BM.(BM+2R)$
$BT^2 = BN.BF$
$\triangle ABC: 12^2+ BC^2 = AC^2$
T.Menelaus: $\triangle ABC-BF: \frac{BE}{AB}.\frac{AC}{CF}.\frac{FN}{BN}=1$

How are $F,N$ defined ?

@Jean Marie: Apparently, there is another invariant at play, similar to the one OP herself has recently presented. Because otherwise then the problem would not be determined. In other words, it seems that another figure can be drawn posing the same problem and in which the answer would seem to be different. Sorry for the bad English. (Vous est au petit matin maintenant, je suis â 6.30 p.m. dans mon pays. Salut)

Anyway, in your figure the lenghts of  $\overline{EB}$ and $\overline{BT}$ are distinct.

@JeanMarie The correct answer would be 6m


Comment: As can be seen in figure BC is not necessarily equal to AB. IF BG is 3(as answer says) then you need to show that the intersection of a circle with radius 3 with circle s is point G and another is N which is also the intersection of CE and s. Or; where s and CE intersect is always the tangent point of BN on s and $NB=BE$ which results in another tangent BG is also 3.
Update: In figure b ,point A, E, N and F are cyclic .The power of point B to the circle  s is:
$BN\times BF=BE\times BA=3\times 12=36$
Power of point B to circle t is:
$BT^2=BN\times BF=36\Rightarrow BT=6$

You are right..I corrected the answer

Could you solve it algebraically?

The answer was initially given as 3, which is incorrect. This GeoGebra sketch confirms the amended answer of 6. This does not provide a solution, but may be useful nonetheless. Observe that $\overline{BT}$ remains constant as point $B$ is moved around point $A$. In this construction, point $F$ is located such that $\angle BFC \cong \angle AEC$.


Note: The congruence was observed. I did not derive the position of point $F$.

the correct answer is 6..already corrected

$
\angle GHC = 90^o \\
\triangle EBC \sim \triangle GHC\\
\angle CFH  =180^o -\angle HGC\\
\angle AE H +\angle HFA = 180^o \implies AEHF_{inscr.}\\
BT^2 = BH.BF = BE.BA = 36 \therefore\boxed{ BT = 6}$

